# Proof orthogonal vector

Tags: vector-spaces

I have to prove the following: given $\vec{x}, \vec{y} \in \mathbb{R}^n$, show that
$$
|\vec{x} + \vec{y}| = |\vec{x} - \vec{y}| \Leftrightarrow \vec{x} \perp \vec{y }.
$$

---

However, I am not sure how to proceed. 
I know that $|\vec{x}| = \sqrt{\vec{x}\cdot\vec{x}}$, so it would be

$|\vec{x} + \vec{y}| = \sqrt{(\vec{x}+\vec{y})\cdot (\vec{x}+\vec{y})}$ and the same for the minus sign, which would give the binomial formula. However I can't prove the implication.

---

Would appreciate any help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that $\def\abs#1{\left|#1\right|}\def\<#1,#2>{#1\cdot #2}\abs{z}$ is always non-negative, for all $z \in \def\R{\mathbf R}\R^n$. Hence 
$$ \abs{x+y} = \abs{x-y} \iff \abs{x+y}^2 = \abs{x-y}^2 $$
Using the binomial formula, we have 
$$ \abs{x\pm y}^2 = \<x,x> \pm 2\<x,y> + \<y,y> $$ 
Taking the difference, we have 
$$ \abs{x+y}^2 - \abs{x-y}^2 = 4\<x,y> $$
Now one side is zero, iff the other is, and we are done.

Answer (score 0):

**Hint:** Forget about the radical and deal with squares (because $|a|=|b|$ if and only if $|a|^2=|b|^2$).

Note that $|x\pm y|^2 =(x\pm y)\cdot(x\pm y) = |x|^2 + |y|^2 \pm 2x\cdot y$.

What happens if you equate $|x+y|^2$ and $|x-y|^2$?